# Conditional Help in Python

Tags: python

I needed some help in understanding the following code:

```
nextState = ((nextx, nexty), self.corners) if self.currentPosition not in self.corners else ((nextx, nexty), tuple([i for i in self.corners if i != self.currentPosition]))
successors.append((nextState, action, 1))
```

Can someone show me what this conditional statement would look like in multiple lines rather than just a one line if statement?

Answer (score 0):

As an `if` statement, this would be:

```
if self.currentPosition not in self.corners:
    nextState = ((nextx, nexty), self.corners)
else:
    nextState = ((nextx, nexty), tuple([i for i in self.corners if i != self.currentPosition]))
successors.append((nextState, action, 1))
```

This is essentially Python's form of a [ternary operator](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#is-there-an-equivalent-of-c-s-ternary-operator).

Comment: Thank you! This helped so much, I was close. I was missing assigning everything to the variable after the else statement. I'd overlooked it in my confusion.